# Check a list of lists against another and output based on specific matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have two lists of lists.

```
List1 = [['X', '1', 'P'], ['D', '2', 'Y']]

List2 = [['X', '1', 'Y'], ['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E']]
```

Note: list2 will always contain more items than list1.

I would like to check list1 against List2 and return all the list1 values that both list elements [0] and [1] are the same.

So my final result should be:

```
List3 = [['X', '1', 'P']]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers here assume that the *matching* lists are in the same order. Here's a solution that doesn't:

```
list1 = [['X', '1', 'P'], ['D', '2', 'Y']]
list2 = [['X', '1', 'Y'], ['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E']]

list3 = [i for i in list1 if tuple(i[:2]) in [tuple(i[:2]) for i in list2]]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[['X', '1', 'P']]
```

To make the above more efficient, you can cache in a variable the list inside the conditional of the list comprehension

```
list1 = [['X', '1', 'P'], ['D', '2', 'Y']]
list2 = [['X', '1', 'Y'], ['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E']]

list2_tuples = set(tuple(i[:2]) for i in list2)
list3 = [i for i in list1 if tuple(i[:2]) in list2_tuples]
print(list3)
```

Output:

```
[['X', '1', 'P']]
```

Comment: Your second example still depend on the order being the same.

Comment: Why is that? If `list2` is in a reversed order, `('X', '1')` would still be in `list2_tuples`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood — I took you to mean that `['1', 'X', 'Y']` would count as a match with `['X', '1', 'P']`

Comment: Yeah, not want I meant and not what the OP asked for. I meant the other solutions won't work if `List2 = [['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E'], ['X', '1', 'Y']]` as they match the two lists using the elements with the same index

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this efficiently it to make a lookup set with tuples of the values you are interested in. Then you can make a simple list comprehension to filter:

```
List1 = [['X', '1', 'P'], ['D', '2', 'Y']]
List2 = [['X', '1', 'Y'], ['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E']]

lookup = set(tuple(l[:2]) for l in List2)

[l for l in List1 if tuple(l[:2]) in lookup]
# [['X', '1', 'P']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for l1 in list1:
    for l2 in list2:
        if l1[0] == l2[0] and l1[1] == l2[1]:
            print(l1)    # or append to list3
```

Or, in a list comprehension:

```
list3 = [l1 for l1 in list1 for l2 in list2 if l1[0] == l2[0] and l1[1] == l2[1]]
```

It's simple, iterate over both the lists, and check for elements 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code:

```py
list1 = [['X', '1', 'P'], ['D', '2', 'Y']]
list2 = [['X', '1', 'Y'], ['Y', '2', 'H'], ['T', '6', 'E']]
similar_elements = [list1[i] for i in range(len(list1)) if list2[i][:-1]==list1[i][:-1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```py
[e1 for e2 in List2 for e1 in List1 if e1[:2] == e2[:2]]
```